# Google Chrome command line switch to emulate a device size?

Tags: css, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Does anyone know what are the Google Chrome command line switches that I can use to emulate the device size?

The component that I want to test contains the CSS @media query min-device-width/min-device-height. I tried using the --window-size and --user-agent but I have no luck with those.

Basically, I am trying to write a webdriver test for this component.

Comment: You could execute javascript from webdriver to resize the browser window.

Answer (score 2):

There are switches which might help you do that `--window-size`, `--user-agent` and `--use-mobile-user-agent` .Here is the [full list of switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). [This article](http://mergy.org/tag/command-line-args-to-google-chrome-canary/) also explains how to save those settings as a new app.

I was also looking for a way to trigger chrome mobile emulation tool by command line or using webdriver or simply karma, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958721/start-chrome-emulation-from-command-line) and [chromium team](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/mKDeMepwdgE/q3X3rNn2wFAJ) there is no such option yet, but a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373169&thanks=373169&ts=1400050662) has been filled up you can vote for.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Chrome does not really support this function, but Chrome Canary is exactly what you are looking for.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation