# How to force links opened from Chrome app mode remains in app mode

Tags: google-chrome

I can start chrome in app mode by `chrome.exe --app=http://mywebsite.com`

However the problem is, from `mywebsite.com` any link that opens a new window will then open a full chrome window, i.e. with address bar, bookmarks and etc.

Is it possible to force chrome to remain in the app mode so all links will be opened in an 'app-mode' window too.

Thanks

Comment: very interested in a solution as well

Comment: This question fits better to "super user", maybe as a follow up question to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/33548/starting-google-chrome-in-application-mode).

Comment: Have you tried to use chrome.exe --kiosk http://mywebsite.com ? I read it in another answer some time ago, I'll search it

Answer (score -1):

Can you give more context in your question? (What you are you trying to accomplish, in what scenario)

this functionality doesn't look to be available from a bash or cmd command:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647808/6791342
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/mKDeMepwdgE/q3X3rNn2wFAJ

However, I remember this option being available running Selenium UI-tests in Java which utilizes ChromeDriver

- https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation